# Can't import Dispatch libraries into my Scala project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, rest, scala-dispatch

I am currently working on getting my Scala setup running in Eclipse. I am trying to use Dispatch for HTTP/REST.

It all seems to work fine, up until the point where I try to import the libraries to use them.
Here is what I have done:

I installed [eclipse(Luna)](https://eclipse.org/luna/) and the [sbt plugin](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Using-Plugins.html).

I made a new Scala project and added a new Scala object to that project.
After that I made a build.sbt file that looked like this:

[sbt file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SymTL.png)

and navigated to the source folder in the terminal and ran the sbt update command and it looked like this:

[console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQw0b.png)

To me everything looks fine so far, but when I try to import the Dispatch libraries using this line  import dispatch._  like they do in the tutorial it is not recognized by Eclipse. It simple seems as if the libraries are not there.

I have been going at this for some time and I can't find a solution, maybe I am just missing an obvious step that you could point out to me.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: 1. What version of scala are you using?  It may be that dispatch hasn't been updated in a while, and is not compiled for your version of scala.  2. What error do you get, specifically?  3. Do you get the error when running in the command line?

Comment: 1) When I run this command, util.Properties.versionString I get version 2.11.7.                                                                                                      2) When I try to import the libraries, import dispatch._, Defaults._, I get this error for both libraries "Object not found".                                             3) I have tried to run the dispatcher, using the Dispatcher-example [link](http://dispatch.databinder.net/Dispatch.html) and that worked out.